# Force download of Word Document external shared link

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-users, external-sharing

I am working with a member of HR that is attempting to share a Word Document file with applicants.

I have genereated them a externally shareable link and it works great for opening in Word Online. However, these applicants need to be able to edit their own copy of this document and return it via email.

I found [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/240021/sharepoint-online-enable-direct-download-instead-of-opening-document-when-clic) article that explains how to do it in my-sharepoint, by I need to do it for actual SharePoint Online.

How can I share a document externally and force a download of the file rather than it attempting to open in Word Online?

Answer (score 1):

In the OOTB method to share files with external users, it only allows users to view a document and not download it. It’s by design.

So I recommend you change the guest Sharing URL as the post you provide.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that. Unfortuananly, that method does not work. Using the download link before the guest link requires loging in to access the download.aspx page :( Guess I am standing up an IIS site to share one file.